# Oxidation of amino acids with N-bromosuccinimide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I've recently come across the reaction where an amino acid is oxidised to form an imine by using *N*-bromosuccinimide as reagent and then in hydrolysis it formed an aldehyde moiety.
[image]

The second step is well known (Stephan's aldehyde synthesis using $\ce{SnCl2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$) and I understand that. But I'm unable to understand the mechanism of the first step, how can NBS as a reagent do that?

My initial guess was that  as nucleophilicity and electronegativity are inversely proportional and oxygen is more electronegative than nitrogen from the order of E.N, we can say that nitrogen of $\ce{NH2}$ is more nucleophilic than carboxylic acid oxygen and hence nitrogen's free electrons forms a bond with the bromine of NBS but I'm unable to understand how to proceed next and how is $\ce{CO2}$ formed as products?
Can anyone help with the mechanism? I'm thinking it should be an elimination type mechanism in next step,But I'm not really sure!

Also the yield of product with this method of using NBS as reagent is considerable amount?

Comment: Is the aldehyde correctly rendered? Product seemingly should be $\ce{R - CHO}$ with no bend between.

Comment: The process is an oxidation, not a reduction of the amino acid.

Comment: True I forgot that should  be R-CHO, I've made a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is, as you correctly suggest, the N-bromination of the aminoacid as reported by Ramachandran et al [here](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/10.1246/bcsj.63.2397). An electrocyclic reaction then occurs to eliminate CO2 and HBr leaving the imine which on hydrolysis gives the aldehyde and NH3. Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Bromosuccinimide)

[image]